# Javascript d3 no header for 1 of the CSVs

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I've started using d3 to pass some CSV data, and normally my CSV's look like

```
num,value
1,2
3,1
5,2
```

but I'm loading one CSV with the filename "sample2.csv" which doesn't have any headers, and simply looks like

```
5,3
7,5
```

, the code I'm using looks like

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "sample1.csv").defer(d3.csv, "sample2.csv").defer(d3.csv, "sample3.csv")
.await(function(error, sample1, sample2, sample)
{
}
```

I've read that for the CSV without headers, you need to use csvParseRows

Is this correct? And how could I pass csvParseRows into my code for "sample2.csv"

Does anyone know much about d3 and how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Was typing an answer, but realized it overlapped to much with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274040/7106086). Essentially the same except you don't concatenate a row of headers and use d3.csvParseRows rather than d3.csvParse, I can add an answer if it isn't clear.

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid

Thanks. I had a look on that page, but none of the examples use defer and this is where i'm stuck, i'm not sure where I add csvParseRows when using the defer method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So I believe im making progress. I have done this to "sample2.csv", but i'm getting the error "t.charCodeAt is not a function"

`d3.queue()`
`.defer(d3.csv, "sample1.csv").defer(d3.csv, "sample2.csv", function(text)`
`{`
`console.log(d3.csvParseRows(text));`
`}`
`).defer(d3.csv, "sample3.csv")`
`.await(function(error, sample1, sample2, sample)`
`{`
`}`

any suggestion on why? thanks

Comment: I'll see if I can create an example after work. Limited ability to do so right now.

Answer (score 0):

If using d3.queue, you can parse the text of the csv as usual, then in the await function, you'll need to parse rows:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.text,"test.csv")
  .await(ready);
  
function ready(error, text) {
    var csv = d3.csvParseRows(text);    
    console.log(csv);
    /* use csv data */
}
```

The csvParseRows method takes  a string of text representing the contents of the file, not the url of the file. We can get those contents with d3.text, process it once we've loaded it.

---

With d3v5 an higher though we'd not need d3-queue as we can use a very similar approach without:

```
d3.text("test.csv").then(ready)
  
function ready(text) {
    var csv = d3.csvParseRows(text);
    
    console.log(csv);
    /* use csv data */
}
```

And if we had many files:

```
Promise.all([d3.text("file1.csv"),d3.text("file2.csv")]).then(ready);
  
function ready(files) {
    var csvs = files.map(function(file) {
        return d3.csvParseRows(file);
    });
    
    console.log(csvs);
    
    /* use csv data */
}
```